# a beginners Q regarding multiple functions

Tags: c++

I just need some help with a simple problem.. I'm trying to learn C++ as i want to get into game programming, I have previous programming experience, but not in C++.. My question comes a little like this. I'm making a dummy console application where it will take the numbers of your current XYZ and compare it to a box of coords.. [x1,z1,y1 / x2,y2,z2] and check if you're within this area.. now i can do that on its own.. my question is, How would you write up something that would allow you to reuse this function but have a different output, Eg if its within X box then do X, if its in Y box then do Y .. This is what i currently have..

```
    void withinRange(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2)
{

    if (cCoordx > x1 && cCoordy > y1 && cCoordz > z1 && cCoordx < x2 && cCoordy < y2 && cCoordz < z2)
    {

    }

}
```

I'm not really sure how to expand on this to make it able to be a reusable function..

Comment: Use a bool as return value and do the stuff what it is supposed to do for each box outside that function.

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> How would you write up something that would allow you to reuse this function but have a different output, Eg if its within X box then do X, if its in Y box then do Y

1. Write different functions that check whether the value is in X box or Y box.
2. Implement `withinRange` using the other functions.
3. Use the returned values of these functions to make decisions in the calling function(s).

```
bool withinXRange(int x1, int x2)
{
   return (cCoordx > x1  && cCoordx < x2);
}

bool withinYRange(int y1, int y2)
{
   return (cCoordy > y1  && cCoordy < y2);
}

bool withinZRange(int z1, int z2)
{
   return (cCoordz > z1  && cCoordz < z2);
}

bool withinRange(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2)
{
   return ( withinXRange(x1, x2) &&
            withinYRange(y1, y2) &&
            withinZRange(z1, z2) );
}
```

In the calling function:

```
int x1 = <some value>;
int x2 = <some value>;

if ( withinXRange(x1, x2) )
{
    // Do something
}
```